# Binding не выводит свойство на Label

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

В окне есть `Slider` и `Label`.

Вот код:

```
<Slider 
    Value="{Binding MathLevel, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Width="200" />
<Label
    Content="{Binding MathLevel}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="157,250,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

По идее из **ViewModel.cs** должно обновляться свойство `MathLevel` при изменении значение `Value` (и сразу менять само `Value`). А на `Label` выводить `MathLevel` при обновлении.

Но почему-то работает только первая часть замысла. `Content` как был **0** так и остался сколько не меняй значение `Value` у слайдера.

### Вот свойство из ViewModel.cs

```
public int MathLevel
{
    get => user.Skills[0].Level;
    set {
        user.Skills[0].Level = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Math skill level");
    }
}
```

### А вот User.cs

```
class User
{
    string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Skill> Skills {get;set;} = new List<Skill>()
    {
        //Тут инициализация null нет, все ок.
    }
}
```

### P.S

У меня на форме также находится `TextBox` и для него тоже есть привязка, только к другому свойству в VM. Так вот если `Label` код заменить на вот такой:

```
<Label
    Content="{Binding Name}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="157,250,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

### И вот свойство Name из ViewModel:

```
public string Name
{
    get => user.Name;
    set{
        user.Name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}
```

То значение из `TextBox` отлично заноситься в свойство из VM, а потом и на `Label`

Comment: Не состыковка у вас: `из ViewModel.cs должно обновляться свойство MathLevel`, то есть у вас в роли `DataContext` должен быть установлен `ViewModel.cs`, ок. Далее вы пишете `на форме также находится TextBox` (кстати в WPF принято говорить Окна) и устанавливаете привязку `Content="{Binding Name}"`, смотрим где этот `Name`, я лично вижу его в `User.cs`, то есть этот класс у вас установлен в роли `DataContext` получается, или же все таки  `ViewModel.cs`? Что у вас в отладке пишет программа? И укажите наверно весь XAML...

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged("Math skill level");` - у вас реально так написано?

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, было так написано. Я не знал что нужно передавать именно имя свойства.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у меня тоже свойство в VM есть `Name` реализовано точно так же как и MathLevel. Я просто не знал что нужно в OnPropertyChanged() передавать именно имя свойства

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мы не видим всего кода, но потому что продемонстрировано можно предположить, что ошибка в **ViewModel.cs**, а именно в сеттере *MathLevel*. В событие *PropertyChanged* интерфейса *INotifyPropertyChanged* нужно передать имя свойства, которое изменилось. Так работает Binding в WPF. Т.е. попробуйте сделать следующее:

```
public int MathLevel
{
    get => user.Skills[0].Level;
    set {
        user.Skills[0].Level = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MathLevel");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Так видно же сразу - вы пишите в сеттере свойства какую-то белиберду:

```
OnPropertyChanged("Math skill level");
```

А должны писать имя свойства, которое должно производить уведомление:

```
OnPropertyChanged("MathLevel");
```

А если реализуете интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged с использованием атрибута [CallerMemberName](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2), вот так:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

то можете вообще не указывать имя свойства:

```
public int MathLevel
{
    get => user.Skills[0].Level;
    set {
        user.Skills[0].Level = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```